# RPI2 raspban wheezy on can't install autoconf

Tags: raspbian-wheezy, apt

I am using a raspberry pi 2 model b running raspbian wheezy. I am trying to install a package `autoconf` and it says:

`$sudo apt-get install autoconf
E: no such package autoconf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install autoconf`. Make sure you have an active internet connection. You can confirm it by `ping -c 4 google.com`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please edit your answer. You forgot the `install` command ...`&& sudo apt-get install autoconf`.

Answer (score 2):

That message means that apt can't find autoconf in it's package lists. The package definately exists in the raspbian repositories so it seems like you have some kind of local problem.

First if you have not run "sudo apt-get update" do so and then try the install again.

If apt-get update gives errors post them so we can advise further. If apt-get update succeeds without any errors but the apt-get install still fails then post the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list